# Text goes beyond border of the window frame

Tags: windows, notepad++

in Notepad++ the line of text goes beyond the window frame::

[image]

However, I would like to have it so the text does not go outside the frame:

[image]

How do I do this in Notepad++?

Comment: Obviously switching on the display of line numbers creates this effect. Did you at least resize the window or stop/restart the application when you toggled the line number display?

Comment: @JanDoggen In this case I don't believe it is the "line numbers" as they are only 4/5 characters wide, where as the 'missing' text is 12 characters. Enabling word wrap will fix the problem (and still allow diaply of line numbers). See my answer.

Comment: So far for the OP uploading suggestive pictures....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### How do I stop text going beyond the right edge of the window?

You need to turn on "Word wrap" if your text is wider than the window can display.

To toggle "Word wrap:

- menu "View" > "Word wrap" or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]